# How do i remove a whole repository in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

would hg remove * when i am at the level of where my local repository copy is , remove it, then of course hg commit and hg push

Comment: Are you trying to wipe out a repo for the purpose of starting over? Can you add a few sentences about what you're doing?

Comment: yes, i am trying to remove a repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to completely remove any bindings to Mercurial for a directory containing a repository you can just delete the .hg folder in it.  Is that what you mean?